# stored procedure broke in release mySQL 8.0.22

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, session-variables, local-variables

With the release of mySQL 8.0.22, this stored procedure

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`workbench`@`%` PROCEDURE `loopPIDCreate`( IN startPID VARCHAR(4) , IN i INTEGER)
    
    SET @cpid = startPID
    
    WHILE ( i > 0 ) DO
    
                SET @PPPX = (SELECT MID(@cpid,4,1));
    
                SET @NNNX = (SELECT `Next` FROM `f930_nonsalespidsequence` WHERE `Current` = @PPPX);
    
                ....[other processing ]
    
                SET @newpid = (SELECT CONCAT(@XNNN,@NXNN,@NNXN,@NNNX));
    
                INSERT INTO `e1p1`.`f940_newpidtable` (SELECT @newpid);
    
                SET cpid = newpid;
                            
            END WHILE;
     END
```

would stop updating values after the first pass through (`i` on its second and subsequent passes as it gets decremented toward 0).

To quote Fred Willard from *A Mighty Wind*, "Hey, what happened?"

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO variable FROM ..` instead of `SET variable = (SELECT ..`

Comment: Thanks Akina.  In this case it's cleaner to keep those variables out of the session scope, so I'll stick with the DECLARE fix as noted in the answer below.  BUT if I ever need to update a variable I want to have available across the session, nice knowing about SELECT...INTO

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct result of [optimizations introduced in mySQL 8.0.22](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-22.html). In particular, "a statement inside a stored procedure is also now prepared only once" apparently applies to session variables as well. They get initialized and evaluated only once, and in every subsequent iteraton they are null (or otherwise undefined).  Update and working version looks like:

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE PPPX CHAR(4);       -- 20201112 New Optimization 8.0.22 requires local instead of session (@var) variables
        DECLARE PPXP CHAR(4);
        DECLARE PXPP CHAR(4);
        DECLARE XPPP CHAR(4);

        [...other processing]

       SET NNNX = (SELECT `Next` FROM `f930_nonsalespidsequence` WHERE `Current` = PPPX);  

-- note the loss of '@', from session to local with matching DECLARE up top
```

The solution is to use properly `DECLARE`-ed local variables in the stored procedure.  With more experience, I would have avoided this pratfall. Session variables work in stored procedures but were never intended to be local variables.  The mySQL optimizer finally caught up to this fact with this latest release.

[A short and useful reference on local variables in stored procedures is here.](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/377/Syllabus/6-StoredProc/variables.html)